# Locating specific keys and corresponding values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote the following piece of code:

```
def all_di(fl):
    dmm = {}
    for k in range(2):
        for i in fl:
            for m in range (len(i)-1):
                temp = i[m:m+k+1]
                if temp in dmm:
                    dmm[temp] += 1.0
                else:
                    dmm[temp] = 1.0
##  return dmm
    p = raw_input("Enter a 2 AA long seq:")
    sum = 0
    for x,y in dmm.iteritems():
        if x == p:
            n1 = y
    for l,m in dmm.iteritems():
        if l[0] == p[0]:
            sum = sum + m
    print float(n1)/float(sum)

all_di(inh)
```

if inh  = `{'VE':16,'GF':19,'VF':23,'GG' :2}`

The code works as follows:

```
Enter a 2 AA long seq: VE
```

result will be = `16/(16+23)` = `0.41`

How it works: the function searches the dictionary `dmm` for the key similar to the one entered in `input` (example taken here 'VE'). It stores its value and then searches for all the key-value pairs that have the 1st letter in common and adds all its values and returns a fraction.

```
VE = 16
**V**E + **V**F = 39
= 16/39 = 0.41
```

What I want: keeping the function intact, I want to have a secondary dictionary that iterates for every key-value pair in the dictionary and stores the fractional values of it in a different dictionary such that:

```
new_dict = {'VE' : 0.41, 'GF':0.90,'VF':0.51, 'GG': 0.09}
```

I don't want to remove the `print` statement as it is the output for my program. I however need the `new_dict` for further work.

Comment: this code prints 0.25 for the example

Answer (score 1):

```
def all_di(fl,p=0):
  dmm = {}
  interactive = p == 0
  if interactive:
    p = raw_input("Enter a 2 AA long seq:")
  if p in fl: 
    numer = fl[p]
    denom = 0.0 
    for t in fl: 
      if t[0] == p[0]:
        denom = denom + fl[t]
  if interactive:
    print numer / denom
  return numer / denom

inh = {'VE':16,'GF':19,'VF':23,'GG' :2} 
all_di(inh)
new_dict =  {x:all_di(inh, x) for x in inh}
print new_dict
```

Comment: @perreal- any way to replace p= 'VE' with a `raw_input`?